# How to run faye server in heroku as heroku supports web sockets now?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, websocket, faye

I have been using faye so far in open shift and now i would like to move it to heroku as heroku seems to support web sockets now but i could not able to get it working. I have the following files.

**config.ru**

```
require 'faye'

Faye::WebSocket.load_adapter('thin')
app = Faye::RackAdapter.new(:mount => '/faye', :timeout => 45)

run app
```

**procfile**

```
web:  bundle exec thin -p $PORT -e $RACK_ENV -R config.ru start
```

but this doesn't work as expected. I usually try to check if the connection could be established using faye mac which could track if the connection is made.

Now when i try to connect it shows up an error in the heroku logs as shown below.

> at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET
>   path=/ host=sample-app.herokuapp.com fwd="123.63.31.209" dyno=web.1
>   connect=1ms service=16ms status=503 bytes=0

So please help me. I have enabled web sockets for the app as said in the heroku blog.

Comment: so, where did you read that this should be supported?

Comment: I have been searching something and somehow managed to get that from https://github.com/ntenisOT/Faye-Heroku-Cedar and it worked with long polling even before heroku supported web sockets.

Comment: Is something wrong in that...

Comment: https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2013/10/8/websockets-public-beta this is the link for Heroku's websocket stuff

Comment: yes, i have read and i have enabled web sockets as said in the blog.